# Best practice for using Page Object Pattern selectors in shadow DOM

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom

What are best practices for accessing selectors, when you use page object pattern? Let's have a simple example:

```
        [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "button-submit")]
        public IWebElement button { get; set; }
```

in most cases you use just `button.Click()` etc., and that's simple, but what if sometimes you need to access the css selector, as you traverse in shadow DOM for example, so you need to write something like `GetShadowElement(anotherButton).FindElement(By.CssSelector("button-submit"));`. 
Is there a way to access this `Using=` from page element while working with `FindElement` method or do i need to extract this into:
`private const string locator = "button-submit";` for example, update my page object element into `Using = locator` and of course later on collect all such examples and put them in static class for constants, etc. Is there a better way for handling that? How do you traverse in shadow DOM with page object?